# CREATE DATABASE in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Why does the Owner show "postgres" after creating a new PostgreSQL database? How can I create a new database with my DB user as the owner? My DB user has the privilege to create a database.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html

Answer (score 2):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html) you can specify the owner when creating the database

```
create database my_new_dabase
    OWNER = sunday_ezeilo;
```

This assumes that you already have a role/user named `sunday_ezeilo`